# Can I consume websocket on Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, node.js, websocket

I want to create a websocket server using Node.JS (Socket.io), but have a Java Swing client to consume it. Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: Do you need the server to be websocket-based if you intend to connect a Java client to it and not a web browser?

Comment: @millimoose yes... I already have a server with Socket.io, but need to implement a Java Swing client to consume it...

Comment: Does socket.io actually support connecting to its servers using anything but the client library? At least their documentation doesn't really mention how to use their low-level transports. (They do mention AJAX polling is one of them though.)

Comment: @millimoose they implement WebSocket specification and fallback to Ajax Polling, etc if browser not support

Comment: So use a regular HTTP client library and use AJAX polling then.

Comment: I found this: https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket  but doesn't know if works on Swing app (I'm new to Java...)

Comment: The fact it's a Swing app shouldn't pose any restrictions whatsoever. (Also: why start a Swing app in this day and age? JavaFX has been around forever.)

Comment: I have a websocket server that handle a simple chat app... my customer wants to use that chat on his Swing app... but this will be consumed by the swing app and website

Comment: Also, what I meant with one of the above comments is that "WebSocket server" and "Socket.io" server do not, near as I can tell, mean the same thing. Socket.io seems to operate at a higher level of abstraction than raw WebSockets, and they do not document how to connect to a Socket.io service using anything but their own custom Javascript-based client library. I.e. even if that Java WebSocket library works your setup *might* be a nonstarter. (It might not if you actually can connect to Socket.io without the help of their client library, but I can't find docs on how to do so.)

Comment: https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client perhaps.

Comment: @millimoose Yeah, Socket.IO is an abstraction over WebSockets and numerous other (fallback) transports. And, the protocol is documented. Just separately. :) https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-spec

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Right. I suppose it'd be more accurate to say that the Socket.io authors don't particularly concern themselves with connecting from other platforms, beyond making this feasible for someone else to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could also adapt a jWebSocket client using these instructions:

http://jwebsocket.org/documentation/installation-guide/android-client

It's aimed to consumers running on Android, but the same applies for desktop applications.